# Recursive SQL function and change tracking don't work together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a recursive function which gives allows me to give any GUID in the heirarchy and it pulls back all the values below it. This is used for folder security.

```
 ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ValidSiteClass
(   

    @GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    WITH previous
AS (   SELECT
           PK_SiteClass,
           FK_Species_SiteClass,
           CK_ParentClass,
           ClassID,
           ClassName,
           Description,
           SyncKey,
            SyncState

       FROM
           dbo.SiteClass
       WHERE
           PK_SiteClass = @GUID
       UNION ALL
       SELECT
           Cur.PK_SiteClass,
           Cur.FK_Species_SiteClass,
           Cur.CK_ParentClass,
           Cur.ClassID,
           Cur.ClassName,
           Cur.Description,
           Cur.SyncKey,
           Cur.SyncState

       FROM
           dbo.SiteClass Cur,
           previous
       WHERE
           Cur.CK_ParentClass = previous.PK_SiteClass)
SELECT DISTINCT
        previous.PK_SiteClass,
        previous.FK_Species_SiteClass,
        previous.CK_ParentClass,
        previous.ClassID,
        previous.ClassName,
        previous.Description,
        previous.SyncKey,
        previous.syncState
FROM
        previous


)
```

I have a stored procudure which then later needs to figure out what folders have changed in the user's heirarchy which I use for change tracking. When I try to join it with my change tracking it never returns the query. For example, the following doesn't ever return any results (It just spins, I stop it after 6 minutes)

```
    DECLARE @ChangeTrackerNumber INT = 13;
DECLARE @SelectedSchema UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '36EC6589-8297-4A82-86C3-E6AAECCC7D95';


WITH validones AS (SELECT PK_SITECLASS FROM ValidSiteClass(@SelectedSchema))

SELECT SiteClass.PK_SiteClass KeyGuid,
       '' KeyString,
       dbo.GetChangeOperationEnum(SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION) ChangeOp
FROM dbo.SiteClass
    INNER JOIN CHANGETABLE(CHANGES SiteClass, @ChangeTrackerNumber) tracking --tracking
        ON tracking.PK_SiteClass = SiteClass.PK_SiteClass
    INNER JOIN validones
        ON SiteClass.PK_SiteClass = validones.PK_SiteClass
WHERE SyncState IN ( 0, 2, 4 );
```

The only way I can make this work is with a temptable such as:

```
    DECLARE @ChangeTrackerNumber INT = 13;
DECLARE @SelectedSchema UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '36EC6589-8297-4A82-86C3-E6AAECCC7D95';



CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
    [PK_SiteClass] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
);
INSERT INTO #temptable
(
    PK_SiteClass
)

SELECT PK_SiteClass
FROM dbo.ValidSiteClass(@SelectedSchema);
SELECT SiteClass.PK_SiteClass KeyGuid,
       '' KeyString,
       dbo.GetChangeOperationEnum(SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION) ChangeOp
FROM dbo.SiteClass
    INNER JOIN CHANGETABLE(CHANGES SiteClass, @ChangeTrackerNumber) tracking --tracking
        ON tracking.PK_SiteClass = SiteClass.PK_SiteClass
    INNER JOIN #temptable
        ON SiteClass.PK_SiteClass = #temptable.PK_SiteClass
WHERE SyncState IN ( 0, 2, 4 );

DROP TABLE #temptable;
```

In other words, the CTE doesn't work and I need to call the temptable.

First question, isn't the CTE supposed to be the same thing (but better) than a temptable?

Second question, does anyone know why this could be so? I have tried inner joins and using a where and in clause also. Is there something different about a recursive query that might cause this odd behavior?

Comment: "For example, the following doesn't work." In what way does it not work? Error? Unexpected results? Spontaneous combustion?

Comment: It doesn't return any results. It spins for over 6 minutes (I never saw if it returns past that time). The regular query of 1400 recursive records returns in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you have a table-valued function, you'd just include it like it was a regular table (assuming you have a parameter to pass to it). If you want to pass a series of parameters to it, you'd use `outer apply`, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

I think (maybe) this is more like you want (notice no `with` clause):

```
select
  s.PK_SiteClass KeyGuid,
  '' KeyString,
  dbo.GetChangeOperationEnum(t.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION) ChangeOp
from
  dbo.ValidSiteClass(@SelectedSchema) v
  inner join
  SiteClass s
  on
    s.PK_SiteClass = v.PK_SiteClass
  inner join
  changetable(changes SiteClass, @ChangeTrackerNumber) c
  on
    c.PK_SiteClass = s.PK_SiteClass
where
  SyncState in ( 0, 2, 4 )
option (force order)
```

...which I'll admit doesn't look *that* mechanically different than what you have with the `with` clause. However, you could be running into an issue with SQL Server just picking a horrible plan not having any other clues. Including the `option (force order)` makes SQL Server perform the joins according to the order you put them in...and *sometimes* this makes an incredible difference.

I wouldn't say this is recommended. In fact, it's a hack...just to see WTF. But, play around with the order...and get SQL Server to show you the actual execution plans to see why it might have come up with something so heinous. An inline table-valued function is visible to SQL Server's query plan engine, and it may decide to not treat the function as an isolated thing the way programmers traditionally think about functions. I suspect this is why it took so long to begin with.

Funny enough, if your function were to be a so-called multi-lined table-valued function, SQL would definitely *not* have the same type of visibility into it when planning this query...and it might run faster. Again, not a recommendation, just something that might hack a better plan.

Comment: that worked! When you this is not recommended, what do you think the ramifications could be using the option (force order).

Comment: Oh, it's not bad when it works...that's why they provided it. But it's one of those things that can mask other problems. Often, if SQL Server picks a bad plan it means there might have been missing indexes.

Comment: @done_merson Tucson! I'm jealous. I lived there for 5 years and it's my all time favorite city.